# Как заблокировать тип от удаления в umi-cms

Tags: umi

В модуле "шаблоны данных" есть системные типы данных, которые защищены от случайного удаления.
Можно ли заблокировать от удаления свои типы данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В корень сайта нужно поместить скрипт со следующим содержанием:

```
<?php
  define("CURRENT_WORKING_DIR", str_replace("\\", "/", $dirname = dirname(__FILE__)));
  require CURRENT_WORKING_DIR . '/libs/root-src/standalone.php';
  $typesCollection = umiObjectTypesCollection::getInstance();
  $type = $typesCollection->getType($iTypeID); //здесь ID вашего типа
  $type->setIsLocked(true);
?>
```

Затем запустить скрипт из браузера.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться [UMI.Console](http://ilyar.github.io/UMI.Console/), пример:

```
umi type edit {typeId} --locked=true
```